# How can the hydrosphere be properly used to reduce the load on the lithosphere

Tags: homework, atmospheric-chemistry

The earth is made up of 70% hydrosphere and 30% lithosphere.The space of lithosphere is continually used and it seems there is a threat to a balance ecosystem.Describe how the hydrosphere can be make good use of to reduce the loads on the lithosphere

Comment: This looks like a homework question for which the questioner has made zero effort

Comment: @aretxabaleta Not only that, 'hydrosphere' and 'lithosphere' appear to be used (wackily) incorrectly, so -1 for the teacher, too.